# method to find length of each word

Tags: java

I need a method, which checks that the number of words in String is not bigger than **M** and that the length of each word is not bigger than **N**.

```
int n;
int m;
@Override
    public String checkMessage(String message) {
        if (message.length()!=0)
        {String[]list=message.split(" "); // message.length =here we found how much words

if (message.length<m) || **????**< n {//do smth}
```

but how can i find length of each word and compare it with n? 
Thanks

Comment: What's the expected output: (1) When `message` does not meet the criteria (2) When `message` meets the criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job attempting to solve it. What you need to do is loop through each word in the array of words and check if the length of each exceeds N.

```java
    @Override
    public String checkMessage(String message, int n, int m) {
        String[] words = message.split(" ");

        if (words.length > m) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("The number of words (%s) exceeds the max (%s)", words.length, m));
        }

        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.length() > n) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("The word %s exceeds the maximum word length %s", word, n));
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
```

EDIT: With single condition as requested in comments

```java
    public String checkMessage(String message, int n, int m) {
        String[] words = message.split(" ");

        if (words.length > m || Stream.of(words).anyMatch(word -> word.length() > n)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                    "The number of words (%s) exceeds the max (%s) or word length exceeds max.", words.length, m));
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a beginner so I do not know yet "throw new IllegalStateException ". But how can  I put these two conditions in one method? It must look like  if (a>m || b>n) {sout("Hi"). Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that with Java8 for example. I'll update my answer. It's worth noting that when you throw an exception like IllegalStateException you can catch it and handle it appropriately!

Comment: No problem man, keep asking questions where you attempt to solve them! Best of luck on your journey :)